Coroutine Dispacher missing in KMP
I'm currently learning KMP and Compose Multiplatform. I'm using voyager as navigation and substitute to viewmodel.
Here's the code for Screen Model, just simple data retrieving. Already test this part standalone and didn't cause any issue.
class MainScreenModel : ScreenModel {

    private val _manga: MutableStateFlow<List<MangaDto>> = MutableStateFlow(emptyList())
    val manga = _manga.asStateFlow()

    init {
        screenModelScope.launch {
            _manga.update {
                Greeting().getPopularManga()
            }
        }
    }
}

And here is the screen
internal class MainScreen : Screen {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {

        val screenModel = rememberScreenModel { MainScreenModel() }
        val searchQuery by screenModel.searchQuery.collectAsState()
        val manga by screenModel.manga.collectAsState()

        Column(
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = searchQuery,
                onValueChange = { _newSearchQuery: String ->
                    screenModel.onEvent(
                        MainScreenModel.MainScreenEvent.OnSearchQueryChanged(
                            _newSearchQuery
                        )
                    )
                },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
                leadingIcon = {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                },
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                ),
                placeholder = {
                    Text(
                        text = "Search",
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    )
                },
                modifier = Modifier.width(700.dp)
            )

            LazyVerticalGrid(
                columns = GridCells.FixedSize(150.dp),
                contentPadding = PaddingValues(4.dp),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(6.dp)
            ) {
                items(manga) { manga_ ->
                    MangaCard(
                        id = manga_.id,
                        title = manga_.attributes.title.en
                            ?: manga_.attributes.title.romanized.orEmpty(),
                        imageUrl = "https://uploads.mangadex.org/covers/${manga_.id}/${manga_.relationships.find { it.type == "cover_art" }?.attributes?.fileName.orEmpty()}",
                        onClicked = {

                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The problem only occur in desktop platform with message:
[CoroutineName(ui.MainScreen:ui.MainScreenModel:default:ScreenModelCoroutineScope), StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelled}@66207bc1, Dispatchers.Main[missing]]

I already added the coroutine core into commonMain dependencies block. Also i make sure if the version of coroutine android on android specific is the same with the core.
Here is github repo if more context is required: Repo URL

Does this answer your question?

Yes thanks. I need the swing for main dispatcher on my desktop version

You're welcome! I would appreciate it if you would upvote both my answer and the question - votes are the best way to say thank you on StackOverflow!

yes, i did that. Pardon my rudeness, i was too excited previously to code again
